# Post Array from Ext.Net store into ASP.NET MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, extjs

I know there are other questions on the forum regarding this but found ho helpful solution up to now.
I have a controller so defined:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(int id, IList<MyObject> data)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, message = "saved!" });
    }
```

A Json Array of `MyObject` is inside a JsonStore and sent up on the `submitData()` function call. I can see everything is sent up correctly, the "data" parameter is an array of MyObject, if I manually do `JSON.Deserialize<IList<MyObject>>(data)` I get exactly what I need, which means that data is a valid json string... in the Headers I can see the "application/json" content-type.
I am using the `JsonValueProviderFactory` already, but it does not help. From my understanding it seems that the value provider should easily map arrays into IList, so I am wondering if I am doing something wrong...

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
As noted in one comment I have a slightly different use scenario: I am actually posting this data through a Store.submitData() call... apparently, even though the headers are similar, the store submit does not work because it actually generates a string.

Does anyone have any knowledge on how to force the store to do something similar to JSON.stringify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown your client code but the following should work fine:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '@Url.Action("update", new { id = "123" })',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    params: JSON.stringify({ 
        data: [
            { foo: 'value 1' },
            { foo: 'value 2' },
            { foo: 'value 3' }
        ]
    }),
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

It assumes that `MyObject` is defined like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

but of course it could be just any complex object.

Comment: Cool, that is exactly what was needed. It needs to be noted that this works even without the JsonValueProvider.

As a side note, I am actually posting this data not with an Ajax Request but through a Store.submitData() call... apparently, even though the headers are similar, the store submit does not work because it actually generates a string.

Does anyone have any knowledge on how to force the store to do something similar to JSON.stringify?

Comment: @Tallmaris, a JsonValueProvider is built-in ASP.NET MVC 3. That's why it works. This will never work in ASP.NET MVC 2 if you don't write a custom value provider.